# Add operation to save method of abstract save method of parent model in Django

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-inheritance

I create base model and inherit that in all of my models. This is my `BaseModel`:

```
class BaseModel(models.Model):
    create_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    update_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    created_by = models.ForeignKey('UserManager.User', default=1, on_delete=models.SET_DEFAULT,related_name='created_%(class)ss')
    updated_by = models.ForeignKey('UserManager.User', default=1, on_delete=models.SET_DEFAULT,related_name='updated_%(class)ss')

    class Meta:
        abstract = True
        ordering = ['create_date']

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.user = kwargs.pop('user', None)
        if self.user:
            if self.user.pk is None:
                self.created_by = self.user
            self.updated_by = self.user
        super(BaseModel, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Now, I want to add some operations to `save` method of one of child models like this:

```
class Child(BaseModel):
    # Some fields go here. 
    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        # Some operations must run here.
```

But `save` method of child model does n't run anymore!
**How can I use save method of child model with save method of `abastract=True` model?**

Comment: Please only use the version tags, e.g. `django-3.0` if your question is specifically about that version and the answers wouldn't be applicable for other (earlier or later) Django versions, for instance, version migration problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you inherit ChildModel from BaseModel, when you get to the save method in BaseModel 'self.**class**' is still ChildModel. So it finds the super of Child, which is BaseModel, so calls the save in BaseModel.

So just call ,

```
super(ChildModel, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: I don't want to change `save` method of `BaseModel`. I just want to add somethings to `save` method of child model. @mohit-harshan

Comment: ok then just do the save() method in the abstract model and call         super(BaseModel, self).save(*args, **kwargs) itwself . it will refer to child model save only

Comment: ty @mohit-harshan

Comment: @Whale52Hz: I tried combinations of the options suggested here - I think I didn't get it right. The scenario is **not working**. Could you pls let me know the following: **1.** Have you kept the `BaseModel` as it is (_at the top of the page_)? **2.** I tried the `save()` method in the **ChildModel** as `super(BaseModel, self).save(*args, **kwargs)` (i.e. placed the code in the `model class` of the child model). But **unfortunately the field `created_by` is not getting updated at save**. Could you please come back on this?

Comment: @carla How can I help you?

Comment: @Whale52Hz I am using a base model and want to update the user on model save. Exactly as your **test case**. As stated in my previous comment, the field `created_by` is not getting updated at save. Somehow not able to get around the problem. To repeat, I have tried `super(BaseModel, self).save(*args, **kwargs)` in child model's save method. Any pointer?

Comment: @carla  1. Yes I kept this `BaseModel` in my project and all things is good. 2. You must pass `user` object in `request.user` to save method when you modify object.

Comment: @Whale52Hz I am using the `CreateView` for creating model instance. I tried using `created_by = request.user` in the child model `save` method,  but came up with **Error** (_Model object does not have attribute request_), quite naturally. I think I need to put this in the `CreateView` itself.  If so, where do I put it (& how)? Tried using it in the `form_valid` using `created_by = self.request.user` but it is still not being saved.

Comment: @carla just do this:  `instance = Model.get(pk=your_id) instance.save(user=request.user)`